# Yii2 Send Verification to Email

Tags: email, yii2

Anyone who know how to send verification to email after user success register their information on the system....i hope anyone can explain step by step....should i edit in this or have any solution or suggestion:

```
Yii::$app->mail->compose()
 ->setFrom('somebody@domain.com')
 ->setTo('myemail@yourserver.com')
 ->setSubject('Email sent from Yii2-Swiftmailer')
 ->send();
```

I already configure the swiftmailer like this:

```
'mail' => [
         'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
         'transport' => [
             'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
             'host' => 'localhost',
             'username' => 'username',
             'password' => 'password',
             'port' => '587', 
             'encryption' => 'tls', 
         ],
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a configuration for 'mailer ' and not for 'mail' like this 
setting `'useFileTransport' => false`

and the setting the transport for your mail server in this case is gmail
if you use another mail server you must set the related parametr properly.

```
'components' => [
       .........
       'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
        // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
        // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
        // for the mailer to send real emails.
        //'useFileTransport' => true,
        'useFileTransport' => false,//set this property to false to send mails to real email addresses
        //comment the following array to send mail using php's mail function
        'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
            'username' => 'yourusername@gmail.com',
            'password' => 'yourpassword',
            'port' => '587',
            'encryption' => 'tls',
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: ok..i already do this..then how to send verification to email after success register

Comment: If you don't have specific need is better you use User extension like http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-user-management/  these extensions contiain all the functionality you need,  include confirmation email and a lot of other useuf function

Comment: If you use gmail. the port is 587 f you use other mail server you must assign the proper way. For gmail server is mandatory port: 587 and encription: tls